# trying to return a variable with values ​from the bank and returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase realtime database. I'm trying to get the data from the database and return it.

I need to return because I'm calling a function that should do this, get the data from the database and return. But in the function I'm calling this 'getData()' function, the value comes as 'undefined'.

Do I have to use asynchronous functions?? Or have another method. someone explain to me please

```
import { construct_bd } from "../../database.js";

function blog_posts() {
   let section = document.getElementById("blog_posts_container");

   function show() {
      let data = construct_bd.getData("/posts");
    
      console.log(data)
   }
   setTimeout(() => {
      show()
   }, 200);
   ...
}
```

database.js

```
...
// Variables
let database = firebase.database();
...
getData(reference){
    let data;
    database.ref(reference).once("value")
    .then(snapshot => data = snapshot.val())
   .catch(error => console.log(error))
   .finally(() => {return data})
},
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `getData` function returns a promise, then use `await` in your calling function. For example

```
async function show() {
  let data = await construct_bd.getData("/posts");
  console.log(data)
}
```

If `getData` is not a promise you can change it accordingly.

```
getData(reference){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    database.ref(reference).once("value").
      then(snapshot => 
        data =  snapshot.val();
         resolve(data);
       ).catch(
         error => reject(error)
       ).finally(() => 
         reject(data);
       )
    
     });
}
```

Comment: nothing man, keep returning me undefined. I tried now to do it with asynchronous function, but with no result

Comment: what `construct_bd.getData("/posts");` return? a promise?

Comment: exactly! I restructured the code that way ```getData(reference){let data; database.ref(reference).once("value").then(snapshot => data = snapshot.val()).catch(error => console.log(error)).finally(() => {return data})},```